# Subir aplicação localhost para subdominio online (hospedado no meu computador)

Tags: node.js, windows

Sempre apanhei para tudo relacionado a servidores e essas coisas. Estou rodando uma aplicação que usa o famoso [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs), e minha hospedagem não dá suporte para o mesmo. Então, apenas para testes "online" queria fazer minha aplicação "localizada localmente", ter acesso online com um subdomínio online, sendo o meu computador o servidor de tudo.

Li algumas coisas sobre alterar o arquivo "hosts" (eu uso Windows) mas não obtive muito sucesso.

Alguma alma pode me ajudar aqui?

Answer (score 3):

Em primeiro lugar, o DNS (que você chama "subdomínio online") deve ter uma entrada apontando para o seu IP.

Em segundo lugar, ao subir uma aplicação escrita em [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs), ela já está em teoria exposta à internet. O que seria necessário fazer é um reapontamento de porta, que pode ser feito por um software chamado de **proxy reverso**, como o [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html), por exemplo, e a liberação da porta no Firewall.

Em terceiro lugar, o que o arquivo `hosts` faz é simular essa entrada DNS apenas na sua máquina. Ele não replica o DNS para a internet. Quem faz isso é a autoridade DNS que detém seu domínio.

Em quarto lugar, o interessante no seu lugar seria fazer o deploy da aplicação em uma máquina que não seja a sua. [Aqui](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Node-Hosting) tem uma lista de servidores que suportam o Node.js.

Answer (score 2):

Se você realmente deseja ver a sua aplicação na sua máquina online em algum domínio, já tentou [DDNS](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Internet/Protocols/DNS/Service_Providers/Dynamic_DNS/)? [noip](http://www.noip.com/) por exemplo? Já tornei minha máquina acessível online via subdomínio noip + configurações no meu roteador. Meu roteador utiliza DD-WRT e tem funcionalidade para atualização automática do meu ip em serviços tipo noip, assim que conecto, o roteador manda um comando com meu novo ip pro noip e o noip configura o domínio pra apontar pra minha máquina. Também é possível encontrar serviços de DDNS que aceitam domínio pessoal, antigamente se não me engano DNSPark oferecia isso e eu usava. Outra coisa é que, conexão DSL não empresarial, tipo speedy, vai bloquear acesso na porta 80, 8080 e outras comuns para servidores.